# Flask server not updating after first run

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server set up to handle move data from a chessboard online. The moves data is correct and is updated very second.

Flask server

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
import re
import os
import chess
from stockfish import Stockfish
import psutil
import atexit

def cleanup():
# Iterate over all running processes
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        # Check if this is the process we're looking for
        if proc.info['name'] == 'sf.exe':
            # Kill the process
            proc.kill()
            print('Process killed')
            break
cleanup()
stockfish = Stockfish(path="sf.exe", depth=20, parameters={"Threads": 1})
atexit.register(cleanup)
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

movestate = None
last_movelist = []
b_mlist = []
board = chess.Board()
ucilist = []
movelist = []
@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    global movelist
    data = request.get_json()  
    moves = data.get('moves')
    movelist = re.sub(r'^\d+\..*', '', moves, flags=re.MULTILINE).split()
    get_moves(movelist)
    
    color = data.get('player')
    username = data.get('username').strip()
    rating = data.get('rating')
    return jsonify({"message": "Data received successfully!", "movelist": movelist}), 200

def get_moves(movelist):
    global board
    board = chess.Board()

    for move in movelist:
        try:
            
            uci = board.parse_san(move)
            ucilist.append(uci)
            board.push_san(move)
        except:
            pass

    return board, board.fen(), movelist, ucilist

def engine(board):
    stockfish.set_fen_position(board.fen())
    evaluation = stockfish.get_evaluation()
    top_moves = stockfish.get_top_moves(5)
    return evaluation, top_moves

@app.route('/')
def display():
    board, _, _, _ = get_moves(movelist)
    evaluation, top_moves = engine(board)
    print(evaluation,top_moves)
    return render_template('idx.html', evaluation=evaluation, top_moves=top_moves)

@app.route('/get_updates')
def get_updates():
    board, _, _, _ = get_moves(movelist)
    evaluation, top_moves = engine(board)
    print(evaluation,top_moves)
    return jsonify({'evaluation': evaluation, 'top_moves': top_moves})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and get  the evaluation data here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="evaluation"></h1>
    <h2>Top Moves:</h2>
    <ul id="top_moves"></ul>

    <script>
      function getUpdates() {
    fetch('/get_updates')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById('evaluation').textContent = 'Evaluation: ' + data.evaluation;
            var topMovesList = document.getElementById('top_moves');
            topMovesList.innerHTML = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < data.top_moves.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.textContent = 'Move: ' + data.top_moves[i].Move + ', Centipawn: ' + data.top_moves[i].Centipawn;
                topMovesList.appendChild(li);
            }
        });
}

        setInterval(getUpdates, 500);  // Update every 5 seconds
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is the server doesn't send data after first start, I have to restart it each time a new move is played to get an evaluation.

I tried adding print statements to see if was POSTing and it stops after the first update.